# update last 3 value without an array?

Tags: c++, c, logic

I have to write a program.
where i get infinite number of user input  and 3 variable `f_value , s_value, t_value`

logic is :

If the input did not match with `f_value` then it have to store in `f_value` same as for `s_value and t_value`.

variable should have different value of input If the value is same It has to skip.
e.g.

```
Input  Value:
100
100
102
102
102
102
102

105
105
```

then the output should

```
f_value 105
s_value 102
t_value 100
```

This should be without an array

I try this code :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int number=0 f_value=0, s_value = 0, t_value = 0;

    while (1) {
        printf("-> ");
        scanf("%d", &number)
        if(t_value != s_value){
            t_value = s_value;
        }
        if(s_value != f_value){
            s_value = f_value;
        }
        if (number != f_value){
            f_value = number;
        }


           printf("f_value  %d\n",f_value);
           printf("s_value  %d\n",s_value);
           printf("t_value  %d\n",t_value);
        }

    return 0;      
    }
```

but not get desire output.

Thanks you

Comment: You said that the logic for `s_value` ans `t_value` should be the same as for `f_value`. But, this does not match with the expected output nor with the conditions in your posted code. Please re-read your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description F, S and T will always have the same value.

Initially they are all zero.  First input is 100, which doesn't match F, so we make F=100.  "Same for S and T" so the result is the same; S=T=100.

Next input is 100 which matches, so no change.

Next input is 102 which doesn't match F, so we set F=102.  Again "same for S and T" so S=T=102.  So we can see from running the first three inputs that no matter what is input, according to your description F=S=T at all times.

So how exactly do you get to the proposed output where F, S and T have different values?

Answer (score 0):

The third **if** statement should be first.

Comment: I already try that. then it gives `f_value  105,s_value 105 and t_value 102`